# how many quantifiers can I use?

Tags: javascript

I see the following code:

```
> '<a> <strong>'.match(/^(.*)>/)[1] //greedy
   'a> <strong'
> '<a> <strong>'.match(/^<(.*?)>/)[1] //reluctant
   'a'
```

Where I cannot understand the difference between `*` and `*?`.

Can I use like this too?

`*???` or `*?+`

If I can do such, please explain a bit. Thank you.

Comment: As any explanation of JS regular expressions would tell you, `*` matches the previous item zero or more times, `*?` does so non-greedily. As for `*???`, why don't you try it and see?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 1):

`*?` is not a composition of `*` and `?`. It is a single operator that does lazy matching: instead of trying to consume as much input as possible, it consumes as little as possible. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> If used immediately after any of the quantifiers *, +, ?, or {}, makes the quantifier non-greedy (matching the fewest possible characters), as opposed to the default, which is greedy (matching as many characters as possible). For example, applying /\d+/ to "123abc" matches "123". But applying /\d+?/ to that same string matches only the "1".

As for `x*???` and `x*?+`, they are not valid regular expressions. I get an error if I try to use them.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```
* - Matches the preceding character 0 or more times. Equivalent to {0,}.
```

So the .* basically matches everything in the original string.  the < and > characters are left out because they are special characters and need to be delimited.  Hence your result of `'a> <strong'`

```
? - Matches the preceding character 0 or 1 time. Equivalent to {0,1}.
```

Now the .*? means: .* match the preceding string, and then the ? takes effect and says match the first character of the string.  Hence your result of `a`

Now as to your other question.  Neither one of the expressions are valid because the additional question marks / plus sign will cause an error when parsing.

You can test out the expressions [here](http://regex101.com/)